# How to convert the position of an element based on the size of its container

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

This is a bit of a hypothetical question, I hope those are allowed here.

I've been having an issue trying to figure out how to do this calculation, and it seems maddingly simple (which makes it even more frustrating).

Let's say I have a 100x100 child element on a 500x500 canvas that I am able to move around inside that parent. Say the current coordinates of the draggable child element are x=42 and y=30.

```
<Canvas Width="500" Height="500">
 <Grid Background="Gray" Canvas.Left="42" Canvas.Top="30" Width="100" Height="100" />
</Canvas>
```

If I were to **resize** the parent canvas, how would I go about adjusting the child element Top and Left properties so that they would **always** be in a relative position inside the parent, no matter what size the parent is?

As a lot of you know, this functionality is simple to achieve in a Grid (by setting the Horizontal and Vertical Alignments), but the built-in Grid positioning is worthless once you drag the control to another position within the grid.

I would gladly accept any ideas in C#, VB.NET, or XAML if anyone has any idea how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a constant top/left, then the formula is just to keep the offset/size ratio constant.  So:

- old left / old width = new left / new width
- new left = old left * new width / old width
- new left = 42 / 500 * new width

If you want to account for the width of the child, though (which I guess you probably do), then you would subtract its width from the calculation.

- new left = old left * (new width - child width) / (old width - child width)
- new left = 42 * (new width - 100) / (500 - 100)
- new left = (42 / 400) * (new width - 100)

The first approach gives you a proportional top/left:

[image: proportional left]

The second gives you a proportional center:

[image: proportional center]

Comment: Good answer. Just beware of integer division. E.g.: `42 / 400` will be 0. The same goes for `(new width - child width) / (old width - child width)`, maybe not 0, but also not what you expect. You need a floating point division here.

Comment: How to calculate the newTop here?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an event handler to the canvas size changed. Then proportionally set the inner control top and left by inspecting the previous and current size. Determine what the size change factor is and multiply the attached property values for left and top by that factor.

Note the factor will be different for height and top then it will for width and left.

Comment: Can you share some example

Answer (score -1):

what if you use % values for the top and left??

Canvas.Left="10%" Canvas.Top="15%"

Comment: percentage values aren't allowed in XAML ;(